# python - best way to write a list of images

Tags: python, image, list

I have this code, a list of images.

```
self.image0 = gtk.Image()
self.image1 = gtk.Image()
self.image2 = gtk.Image()
[...]
self.image20 = gtk.Image()

self.img = # list of all this 20 images. How to write this?
```

I'm looking for a way to write this list with a short line.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: This question would better fit [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

```
self.img = [gtk.Image() for _ in xrange(20)]
```

Images will be accessible via `instance.img[0]` but not via `instance.image0` anymore.

Comment: Pls, can you approve my (modified) question, because I can't ask a new one anymore! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
self.img = [gtk.Image() for i in range(20)]
```

Comment: Please, can you approve my (edited) question, because I can't ask a new one anymore! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Guillaume, What does `approve` mean? I don't get point of the change.